# Uniform convergence of sequence of complex functions and integral over a curve

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve a problem, its statement is:

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb C$ an open set and $f_n,f:\Omega \to \mathbb C$. Show that if $f_n \rightrightarrows f$ on a curve $\int_{\gamma} \subset \Omega$, then $_{\gamma} f_n(z)dz \to \int_{\gamma} f(z)dz$.

I don't have any idea how can I prove this. Moreover, I have doubts related to the conditions of the statement: wouldn't the functions $f_n$ have to be holomorphic or at least continuous? and $\gamma$ piecewise-smooth differentiable. What conditions do I need for this statement and what would be the idea or sketch of a solution (hints).

Comment: Yes, for the integral to make sense one usually requires at least *some* continuity for each $f_n$ and some smoothness for $\gamma$. As a hint for how to proceed with the proof, can you show the following? If $|g| < \epsilon$, then $$\left|\int_{\gamma} g dz \right| < \epsilon \operatorname{length}(\gamma)$$

Comment: Yes, I've seen the proof and that works perfectly: $|\int_{\gamma} f_n(z)dz-\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz|=|\int_{\gamma} (f_n(z)-f(z))dz|\leq \sup_{\gamma}|f_n-f|\operatorname{length}(\gamma)$. Now let $c=\operatorname{length}(\gamma)$. Since $f_n \rightrightarrows f$, given $\epsilon>0$, there is $N \in \mathbb N: \space \forall n \geq N,  : |f_n(z)-f(z)|<\epsilon$. From here one can conclude that $\sup_{\gamma}|f_n(z)-f(z)|\operatorname{length}(\gamma)\leq c\epsilon$. Letting $\epsilon \to 0$ and by the chain of inequalities one proves the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what conditions you need on $\gamma$ will depend on how you've defined the integral, but integrability of the $f_n$ (and thus $f$) should be enough. Let's assume $\gamma$ is smooth. The integral $\int_\gamma f_n$ is by (the usual) definition $\int_0^1 f_n(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)\,dt $, taking $\gamma:[0, 1]\to\Omega$. Break the integral into real and imaginary parts, and use the corresponding result for the real case: For a compact interval $I\subset {\mathbb{R}}$ and integrable $g_n:I\to {\mathbb{R}}$ with $g_n\to g$ uniformly, the function $g$ is also integrable with
$$\int_I g_n\to \int_I g.$$

Comment: I've not tried this but I think it will work, now I'll try it. I appreciate your help

Comment: No problem. Post again if you're still stuck.